# how to include multiple yaml configuration in the same file using js-yaml

Tags: javascript, yaml

am working on a project that include generating `yaml` files and am using `js-yaml` and it did help me so far but the problem is that the library work this way

```
  const yaml = require('js-yaml');

  const kyaml = {
    apiVersion: 'v1',
    kind: 'Namespace',
    metadata: {
      name: username,
    },
  };

  await writeFile(
    `tenant.yaml`,
    yaml.dump(kyaml),
    'utf8',
  );
```

and that will produce

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: sara
```

now my probelm that i need to generate file that have multiple configs separted with triple dashes like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: sara
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: joe
```

so far i did search for some help to achieve that and i didnt find any so any help here is apriciated

Answer (score 0):

js-yaml specifically decided [not to support that](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/issues/564). They give this workaround:

```
[docs_to_dump].map(doc => yaml.safeDump(doc)).join('---\n');
```